# The while loop runs infinite. It is not possible to terminate while loop using timer

Tags: python-2.7, arduino-uno

I am trying to turn on and off the solenoid valves from Python. This toggling mode can be defined before the experiment starts using the infobox. For example, I can define how many time switching can take place (number of toggles) or how long it will take place (time for the toggle in seconds). I am sending two bytes to Arduino, one for the channel selection (1 to 8) and second for the state (0 or 1).

The number of toggles works perfectly. In while loop, I gave instruction myTime > 0 and during every switching I reduced it by one. So the while loop will run until myTime or Number of toggles become zero.

But When I am trying to give time from infobox it becomes an infinite loop. I can give time from infobox and add it to time.time() and trying to compare it in while loop and want to terminate the loop once time.time() become greater than the desired time.

How can I make sure that I can terminate the while loop using both the conditions?

```
Python code: 

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import serial
from time import sleep
import struct
from psychopy import core, data, event, gui, visual 
import time


try:
    arduino = serial.Serial('COM8',19200)
    sleep(2)
    print("Connection to " + 'COM8' + " established succesfully!\n")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

global command

## create a DlgFromDict
info = {'Observer':'jwp', 'Channel':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'],
    'BreathingCycle':4, 'Timer': 0, 'ExpVersion': 1.1, 'Debug Mode': True}
infoDlg = gui.DlgFromDict(dictionary=info, title='TestExperiment',
    order=['ExpVersion', 'Observer'],
    tip={'Observer': 'trained visual observer, initials'},
    fixed=['ExpVersion'])  

myChannel = info['Channel']
myTime = info ['BreathingCycle']
myTimer = info ['Timer']



win = visual.Window(fullscr=True, size=(1536, 864), monitor='laptop') 
#TODO: handle in a different way the screen resolution

instruction1 = visual.TextStim(win, text=u"""Valve on!""")

instruction2 = visual.TextStim(win, text=u"""Valve off!""")

instruction3 = visual.TextStim(win, text=u"""Thank you!""")


if infoDlg.OK:

Mytimer = time.time() + myTimer

while (myTime > 0 or time.time() < Mytimer):     

        if  myChannel == '1': 
            if u'i' in event.waitKeys():
                command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',513)) 
                myTime = myTime - 1
                instruction1.draw() 
                win.flip()
            if u'e' in event.waitKeys():
                command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',512))
                myTime = myTime - 1
                instruction2.draw()
                win.flip()
        elif  myChannel == '2': 
                if u'i' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',257)) 
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction1.draw() 
                    win.flip()
                if u'e' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',256))
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction2.draw()
                    win.flip()
        elif  myChannel == '3': 
                if u'i' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',2049)) 
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction1.draw() 
                    win.flip()
                if u'e' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',2048))
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction2.draw()
                    win.flip()
        elif  myChannel == '4': 
                if u'i' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',1025)) 
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction1.draw() 
                    win.flip()
                if u'e' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',1024))
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction2.draw()
                    win.flip()
        elif  myChannel == '5': 
                if u'i' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',4097)) 
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction1.draw() 
                    win.flip()
                if u'e' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',4096))
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction2.draw()
                    win.flip()
        elif  myChannel == '6': 
                if u'i' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',8193)) 
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction1.draw() 
                    win.flip()
                if u'e' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',8192))
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction2.draw()
                    win.flip()
        elif  myChannel == '7': 
                if u'i' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',32769)) 
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction1.draw() 
                    win.flip()
                if u'e' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',32768))
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction2.draw()
                    win.flip()
        elif  myChannel == '8': 
                if u'i' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',16385)) 
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction1.draw() 
                    win.flip()
                if u'e' in event.waitKeys():
                    command = arduino.write(struct.pack(u'>H',16384))
                    myTime = myTime - 1
                    instruction2.draw()
                    win.flip()

win.close ()  
arduino.close()
```

Comment: The code you've posted has inconsistent indentation - looks like sometimes 4 spaces, sometimes 8. Make sure the code you're trying to run uses one convention consistently. 4 spaces, and not tabs, is recommended.

Comment: Also the only difference between your eight different `myChannel` cases seems to be the numeric value in the `struct.pack` arguments. Is there a good reason you can't just look up those values, say from a dict with `myChannel` as the key, and pass them to a single copy of this code? Doing it that way would probably reduce your chance of unnoticed mistakes.

Comment: @nekomatic Yes, you are right. I must change but that is not an issue here.

Comment: @nekomatic struck.pack is packing those number into two bytes and sending it to Arduino where I am reading the first byte as a channel number like 1, 2, 4, 8 and so on and the second byte is for 1 or 0 to toggle the state. Still, it is also not an issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution since there are functions event.waitKeys() which is basically waiting for a key for an infinite amount of time, that is why time.time() < Mytimer condition is not able to verify. I had to give the maximum waiting time in event.waitKeys().